# Best way to limit visibility to Synchronized Data Extensions in Dev Org?

Tags: marketing-cloud, security, marketing-cloud-connect, roles

What is the best way to limit the visibility to Synchronized Data Extensions as well as their ability to view the Synchronized Data Sources & Objects in Marketing Cloud from other users?

Do we use visibility of folders and limit permissions to contact builder or is there a more preferable approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no specific permissions for Synchronized Data Extensions - you would have to disable overall access to all Data Extensions.

And yes, you are correct, you need to restrict access to Contact Builder to make sure your users don't have access to Synchronized Data Sources.